# Android-Implement swipe tabs in swipe tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three horizontal tabs A, B and C. They have been implemented using FragmentPagerAdapter. Is there a way I can again implement horizontal swipe tabs in each tab.

Tab A
-- Tab 1
-- Tab 2
-- Tab 3

Tab B
-- Tab 1
-- Tab 1
-- Tab 1

and so on.

Comment: I think you mean [`SlidingTabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want nested tabs? If so, I would suggest looking into the documentation for [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

Assuming you have fragments set up for each tab, embed a FragmentStatePagerAdapter within the existing FragmentPagerAdapter.

Copy and convert your activity to a Fragment and embed it in the existing activity.

WARNING!
This design is HIGHLY warned against by Google! I would not suggest using it.

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Keeping the google std in mind I will drop the idea of implementing those